# Uncaught Exception: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql

estoy realizando la siguiente consulta.. y de acuerdo a lo que arroja parece que si esta captando los datos, pero me dice que hay un error de sintaxis... Lo evaluado de muchas maneras y no encuentro el error, si alguien puede identificarlo y ayudarme con esto, se lo agradecería mucho. Para que tengan un contexto Lo que realiza esta consulta es seleccionar un id de un campo select y darle clic en el botón aplicar.. Ese botón ejecuta la consulta que les envió a continuacion

Esta es mi consulta:

```html
public function ApplyFamiliarGroup($selected_group_family=0) {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET selected_group_family = '" . (int)$selected_group_family. "' where customer_id = ".(int)$this->customer->getId()."'");
    }
```

y este es el error que me esta arrojando:

Uncaught Exception: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1
Error No: 1064
UPDATE oc_customer SET selected_group_family = '3' where customer_id = 1

Comment: La última comilla simple está de más, ¿no?. También trata de usar los prepared statements para evitar inyecciones de código